# yarn-cluster mode longer than yarn-client

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn

What is the reason my `pyspark` application on `yarn` cluster takes 4 more longer time in `yarn-cluster` mode than in `yarn-client` one? Is there tricks to boost performance in `yarn-cluster` mode?